# understand inherit abstract method in java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java but not to programming.
I'm reading the book "Beginning Android Games" and there is an [abstract class](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/trunk/ch06-mrnom/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/AndroidGame.java) that gets instantiate [here](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/trunk/ch06-mrnom/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/AndroidFastRenderView.java) (line 10)
and i cant understand how can you instantiate an abstract class ?.

the class is abstract because it inherits an abstract method from class Game (implements Game).

Comment: No, that line#10 does not `instantiate` anything. It is just a declaration. Variable `game` get's its reference, probably instance of a class that fully realizes the abstract class via constructor.

Comment: I do not make Android games but I can tell you this: No abstract class is instantiated on line 10, that is only a reference. Android (?) probably supplies you with a class that extends it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get instantiated. Do you come from C++? If so, you have to remember that that syntax declares a reference, which has no problems being of an abstract type?

Answer (score 2):

`AndroidGame` doesn't get instantiated in the line 10 or in any other line of the class, it is just declared as a member.

It has to be passed to the class' constructor, line 16, and thus this is what happens:

the `AndroidGame` has to be initialized outside the class, and is then passed to the `FastRenderView` to make the current screen accessible for drawing (line 44).

In order to be able to be instantiated elsewhere, one has to derive from `AndroidGame` and override it's abstact methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, that line#10 does not `instantiate` anything. It is just a declaration. Variable `game` get's its reference, probably instance of a class that fully realizes the abstract class via constructor - `AndroidFastRenderView`.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an abstract class that gets instantiated here (line 10):

```
AndroidGame game;
```

**False!** Nothing is being instantiated here. You are declaring a reference to a *type* `AndroidGame`, which is perfectly fine. (A poodle is a type of animal, even though animal is an abstract type). The *underlying* instance must be a concrete subclass of `AndroidGame`.

Instantiation happens using the `new` operator.

- [Creating Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is instantiated on line 10; that declares a reference to an `AndroidGame`.

An `AndroidGame` reference can refer to anything that extends `AndroidGame`.